# Copying/moving a file with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible and I want to copy or move a file using the following code in my Ansible role using my Ansible playbook.

```
- name: Backing up existing ~/.zshrc
  shell: if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then cp ~/.zshrc{,.orig}; fi
  become: true
  become_user: root
  when: installation|success
```

However I am getting this error when I run it, what am I doing wrong?

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
{  
   "changed":true,
   "cmd":"if [ -f ~/.zshrc ]; then cp ~/.zshrc{,.orig}; fi",
   "delta":"0:00:00.002640",
   "end":"2017-04-11 12:32:35.886640",
   "failed":true,
   "rc":1,
   "start":"2017-04-11 12:32:35.884000",
   "stderr":"cp: missing destination file operand after '/root/.zshrc{,.orig}'\nTry 'cp --help' for more information.",
   "stderr_lines":[  
      "cp: missing destination file operand after '/root/.zshrc{,.orig}'",
      "Try 'cp --help' for more information."
   ],
   "stdout":"",
   "stdout_lines":[  

   ]
}
```

Comment: I guess the stderr says it clearly, missing destination for `cp` command:

`cp ~/.zshrc{,.orig} DESTINATION`

Comment: However when i tried running the command locally, it worked just fine, it copied the file for me as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all shells support brace expansion and you can see in the error message `cp: missing destination file operand after '/root/.zshrc{,.orig}'`, that it took the argument literally.

Add the following as an argument to the `shell` module to run the commands in Bash (provided of course that Bash is installed on the target):

```
executable: /bin/bash
```

---

<sup>But overall this is not the most elegant way to do it in Ansible. The troubling thing is why do you need such a task inside an Ansible playbook at all? If it's to take a backup before some other task, which is supposed to modify the `.zshrc` file, then most (if not all) Ansible modules that modify a file provide a `backup` switch to automatically save the previous version.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried that out and it worked, however since you mentioned that brace expansion is not universal, then i'll refrain from using it for a script that's supposed to be universal. Thanks!